# Embed Google Fusion Table Map without setting it as public

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables, publishing, embeddable-web-maps

I would like to make use of Google Fusion Tables and Maps to visualize sales data. The map will eventually be embedded into a webpage so that senior management can access it for decision making purposes as well as company performance evaluation.

The problem is this: The data is sensitive and can not be opened up to public view.

The question is: Is there a way in which a map can be created and embedded without publishing the map to the public?